# Gtk spell checking in python with PyGObject on Ubuntu

Tags: python, gtk

I've created a little helper application using Python and GTK. I've never used GTK before. As per the comment on http://www.pygtk.org/ I used the PyGObject interface.

Now I would like to add spell checking to my Gtk.TextBuffer.

I found a library called GtkSpell and an associated python-gtkspell in the package manager, but when I try to import it it fails with "ImportError: cannot import name TextView from gtk", I presume this means it is using PyGtk instead of PyGObject.

Is there someway to get this working with PyGObject?
Or some other premade GTK spellcheck system I can use instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote one, yesterday because I had the same problem, so it's a bit alpha but it works fine. You could get the source from: https://github.com/koehlma/pygtkspellcheck. It requires [pyenchant](http://packages.python.org/pyenchant/) and I only test it with Python 3 on Archlinux. If something doesn't work feel free to fill out a bug report on Github.

You have to install it with `python3 setup.py install`. It consists of two packages, `gtkspellcheck` which does the spellchecking and `pylocale` which provides human readable internationalized names for language Codes like `de_DE` or `en_US`.

Because there is no documentation yet, an example:

```python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import locale

from gtkspellcheck import SpellChecker, languages, language_exists
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk

for code, name in languages:
    print('code: %5s, language: %s' % (code, name))

window = gtk.Window.new(gtk.WindowType(0))
view = gtk.TextView.new()
if language_exists(locale.getdefaultlocale()[0]):
    spellchecker = SpellChecker(view, locale.getdefaultlocale()[0])
else:
    spellchecker = SpellChecker(view)
window.set_default_size(600, 400)
window.add(view)
window.show_all()
window.connect('delete-event', lambda widget, event: gtk.main_quit)
gtk.main()
```

Comment: Sweet. So it worked with py2.7 out of the box. I took the gtkspellcheck imports and the if else and dropped it into my program. Though setup.py I get an error about locale.db not found, but if I copy the gtkspellcheck and locale directories inside my program it's all good. Also when switching record I reload the buffer text by replacing the gtk.TextBuffer (not sure why I do that), so I had to create the spellchecker after the replacement and call recheck_all. Still, end to end including problems, 10 minutes tops to integrate this, thank you so much.

Comment: GtkSpell really sucks and this library is great so I backported it to PyGtk and added several things: https://github.com/koehlma/pygtkspellcheck/issues/2

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the PyGObject interface is new enough that GtkSpell hasn't been updated to use it yet. As far as I know there is no other premade GTK spell checker.